# How to Set options () from Rscript, run with Rscript.exe

Tags: r, rstudio, scheduled-tasks, headless, rscript

I am trying to set an API `access token` as an option in my `.Rproj` environment. I would like this Rscript to run every 30 minutes and update the `options()` accordingly.

This is the code to run from my Rscript, when run manually using the `source ->` button in Rstudio, the `options() arg` is set correctly and I can get `getOption(td_access_token)`

```
consumer_key <- "EXAMPLE_ACCESS_KEY"

refresh_token <- readRDS("path/to/refresh_token.rds") #an absolute path

new_access_token <- function(){
        rameritrade::td_auth_accessToken(consumerKey = consumer_key, refreshToken = refresh_token)
}

options("td_access_token" = new_access_token())
```

However, when this Rscript is run from the `Windows Task Scheduler` using `Rscript.exe` and then I go to run `getOption(td_access_token)`, the console outputs `NULL`.

Am I mising something? Why does this script not assign the correct data to `options()` when run from outside RStudio, is there any way to fix this?

Comment: Are you using an absolute path with `readRDS` or are you using a relative path? If a relative path, the working directory probably isn't the same when you run from the Task Scheduler.

Comment: @MrFlick I am using an absolute path in my  `Rscript` to avoid this issue...I had been using `here()`, but changed to absolute path to circumvent this. CODE: `readRDS("C:/Users/jjfan/OneDrive/Documents/Finance/R Programming/Custom Risk Ranges/refresh_token.rds")`

Comment: Oh, are you only running the refresh script in the back ground, but have another instance of R up and running? Because `options()` are only set per R session. They are not global or persistent. Each instance of R has it's own private set of options. You can not update the options of one session from a different session.

Comment: @MrFlick, I am running the refresh script in the background, and have tried with the associated project open and closed (i.e no R instances running). What R session would the refresh script in the background be  setting the options to, is this `options` function essentially doing nothing?

Comment: @MrFlick is there anyway to assign this API `access token` globally, perhaps through `.Renviron` or `.Rprofile`, `Sys.setenv`?

Comment: Yes, the `options()` is doing nothing if your script ends there. The Rscript creates it's own session when it runs and everything is forgotten when it ends.

Comment: Ahh okay, is what I am trying to achieve even possible? @MrFlick

Comment: It's not really possible to just set some property somewhere and have it's effects be immediate elsewhere. Solutions like .Renviron and .Rprofile are only read when R starts and the environment variables a program sees are frozen at startup. You'd have to write your own function to return a "current" access token. That function could keep track of the last time it was called and refresh if needed. That function could like in an .Rprofile and be shared across R sessions.